# Grabbing data from Postrgresql to Django

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, database, postgresql

I'm new to Postgresql (and databases in general) and I have one that I filled with a lot of data. But now I need to access that data and create models, register it in the admin, etc. Does anybody know how I can do that?

This is the data that I retrieved:
https://github.com/guenthermi/the-movie-database-import

Comment: Please add the code you have already tried and come up with a concrete problem

Comment: I have no clue how to convert a database to a model, I just need a guidance, because in Youtube/internet I only fount information on how to do it the other way around. But that's because it's not usual to have a database and not the model, it's usual to have the models and not the database.The problem is quiet specific

Comment: Does this help you https://gist.github.com/radzhome/d3b1586b8009ff8e1758cba6a3d92acf?

Comment: That'd be for a single json file, I'd need to have all of my database in some models. Thanks for the suggestion tho

Comment: In the github you have posted, there is a db_schema.json. You should be able to convert this to a django models.py using this script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use the instructions below to connect to your pre-existing DB:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/legacy-databases/